# Why am I getting the An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ',' error

Tags: sql-server

This is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE (Permit,Stampdate) IN (SELECT Permit,MAX(Stampdate) AS Stampdate 
                             FROM mytable GROUP BY Permit)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL SERVER doesn't support this.

You have to switch to a subwquery

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable (Permit integer,Stampdate Datetime)
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytable (Permit,Stampdate) VALUES (1,GETDATE()),
>  (1,DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), '05:30:00'))
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM mytable As t1
> WHERE 
>   EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM
>   
>    ( SELECT Permit,MAX(Stampdate) AS Stampdate  
>     FROM mytable As t2
>        GROUP BY Permit) t2 WHERE  t1.Permit = t2.Permit 
>       AND t1.Stampdate = t2.Stampdate
> )
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Permit | Stampdate              
> -----: | :----------------------
>      1 | 2020-07-02 16:22:06.897
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM mytable As table1
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Permit | Stampdate              
> -----: | :----------------------
>      1 | 2020-07-02 16:22:06.897
>      1 | 2020-07-02 05:30:00.000
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT Permit,MAX(Stampdate) AS Stampdate  
>     FROM mytable As t2
> GROUP BY Permit
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Permit | Stampdate              
> -----: | :----------------------
>      1 | 2020-07-02 16:22:06.897
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff863bd9a8e62fa4d2c052dff00993d3)*